# Does DataFormats.GetFormat allow me to create a new private format?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, base-class-library

I tried the following:

```
DataFormats.Format binaryData = DataFormats.GetFormat("BinaryData");
```

and the returned binaryData.Id is 50151.

Can I assume that "BinaryData" is strictly a name private to me or it is a well known name?

I ask because there is a third party application I am interfacing to (colaSoft) and it pushes to the clipboard a format called `BinaryData` also with the `Id` is also 50151. Is it just a coincidence?  How is the `Id` determined?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for the [DataFormats.GetDataFormat Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588274(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks):

> This method can also be used to register new formats. If the specified format cannot be found, it is automatically registered as a new data format.

This does not answer the part of your question:

> Can I assume that "BinaryData" is strictly a name private to me or it is a well known name?

So the next step is to look at the source code for the method.

```
    public static Format GetFormat(string format) {
        lock(internalSyncObject) {
            EnsurePredefined();

            // It is much faster to do a case sensitive search here.  So do 
            // the case sensitive compare first, then the expensive one.
            //
            for (int n = 0; n < formatCount; n++) {
                if (formatList[n].Name.Equals(format))
                    return formatList[n];
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < formatCount; n++) {
                if (String.Equals(formatList[n].Name, format, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return formatList[n];
            }

            // need to add this format string
            //
            int formatId = SafeNativeMethods.RegisterClipboardFormat(format);
            if (0 == formatId) {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), SR.GetString(SR.RegisterCFFailed));
            }


            EnsureFormatSpace(1);
            formatList[formatCount] = new Format(format, formatId);
            return formatList[formatCount++];
        }
    }
```

You should notice from the code that if the format does not exist if is registed by calling `SafeNativeMethods.RegisterClipboardFormat` that is declared as follows.

```
    [DllImport(ExternDll.User32, SetLastError=true, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    public static extern int RegisterClipboardFormat(string format);
```

Now from the documentation for the [RegisterClipboardFormat function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649049(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If a registered format with the specified name already exists, a new
>   format is not registered and the return value identifies the existing
>   format. This enables more than one application to copy and paste data
>   using the same registered clipboard format. Note that the format name
>   comparison is case-insensitive.
>
> Registered clipboard formats are identified by values in the range
>   0xC000 through 0xFFFF.

From this and the fact that there is only one Clipboard per session, you should be able to infer that the format ID is common in a given session.

As far as how the ID is generated, I would can not answer that part as 
I do not have access to that code.